# I want to submit two queries into my sql, two tables?

Tags: mysql

Sorry if I am not explaining this very well!

I basically have one table called 'items'. In this table I have numerous columns (including names, numbers  etc) but I also have 'price'. Where there are numerous items (all different names, however some are from the same company) I would basically like combine two 'name' price amounts and get a total.

Example of my code so far:

```
SELECT sum(price) as "Total Cost"
FROM items
WHERE item_name LIKE 'Henry% + Pert%';
```

The code works perfectly without the added '+Pert%', so I need to find a way to allow this to be added to the combined total.

Would appreciate any guidance, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for `OR`?

```
SELECT sum(price) as "Total Cost"
FROM items
WHERE item_name LIKE 'Henry%' OR item_name LIKE 'Pert%';
```

Comment: You have saved the day, one of those moments where I have been working on it far too long. Thank you.

Comment: @user3307086 accept the answer and vote up if this answer was helpful!